# Does a powerline adapter performance matter if my Internet speed is less than powerline rated speed?

Tags: home-networking

My question is really basic.

If my best Internet speed is around 30Mbs does it matter if my powerline adapter speed is 100 or 200Mbs.

Logically the system is as fast as its slowest link.

Is logic right?

Answer (score 0):

> If my best internet speed is around 30Mbs does it matter if my
>   Powerline adapter speed is 100 or 200 Mbs.

Nope. Your logic is right. It doesn’t matter what your local powerline network’s performance is if your Internet speed is 30Mbs and your powerline network is maxed at 100Mbs.

It *does* matter if you care about LAN device-to-device speed on that powerline network. Like if you have some kind of media server that needs decent speed for acceptable performance and such.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is correct, but be careful what you're comparing.  Rated speeds are just maximums you shouldn't expect to be able to exceed under the best conditions.  Actual speeds are what governs bottlenecks.

Powerline adapter performance can vary a lot based on the building wiring, and where you need to make the connections.  You could have a situation where the actual performance you realize is far below the rated maximums due to the environment in which you're using it.

In a challenging situation, the operational difference behind what gives you the different maximum rated speeds could make the difference as to whether the actual performance is above or below your Internet speed.  In that situation, your adapter speed would make a difference.